# How to completely clean Spark Session?

Tags: apache-spark

My use-case revolves around either restarting/cleaning the SparkSession per job execution. When I have to clean the SparkSession without restarting, I'm currently only doing `sparkSession.catalog().clearCache();`, but I'm wondering if there're any other entities in the Spark Session I have to clean to ensure that no information gets carried onto the next execution.

Comment: If your Spark session remains the same among different jobs you can use check-pointing and persisting for both RDDs and dataframes in order to free up memory. When using one of those Spark will save the intermediate results in disk and/or in memory freeing the current execution plan and its dependencies. Although, this will not affect cache and is totally independent process. You can use check-pointing with `rdd.checkpoint()` or `df.checkpoint()` for RDDs and dataframes accordingly.